# Counting From X to Y - UILabel - CADisplayLink

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I've implemented a Counting - Label which counts from x to y by a given period of time. Hovewever, I use a `UILabel` and and a `CADisplayLink` to update the text of the `UILabel.

Now, I assume the problem is, that "something" blocks the main thread for a short period of time which ends up, that the "Counting-Animation" looks not very smooth. This means if counting from -2650 to 4000 - it's stops at 2000 by a really short period of time (but long enough to get noticed by the user) and continous afterwards..

My Code looks like:

```
// Create the display link and add it to the runloop -> commonModes
let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector:#selector(CountAnimator.tick))
displayLink.isPaused = true
displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .commonModes)

// Update the text of the label (just assume that there is a non time expensive function which calculates the current count)
fileprivate func tick() {
  self.textLabel.text = currentCount
}
```

I know that it would be the best to find the source why the main-thrad is blocked (Instruments), however imagine that this would be really hard to find and the counter animation has to be work in a smooth way.

Do you have an idea how this counting animation could be done in another way? With Core Animation, `CATextLayer` animation etc. (knowing that the update of the UILabel.text has to be on the main thread)? Do you think the problem could be that anything else blocks the main thread?

P.s. The Counting animation looks like the "Stop-Watch" in Apples' Watch App.

thx

Comment: If you have something blocking the main thread, you're really going to have to resolve that. Any timer mechanism (display link, timer, GCD timer) that is updating the UI is going to have to do that on the main thread, so if the main thread is blocking, none of those mechanisms is going to work well. And display links are really ideally suited for UI updates, so I'd stay with that, personally. You're going to have to find whatever if blocking the main thread.

Comment: Hy Rob, thanks for your answer. Had expected that, but don't want to do it.... Think it's time for Time-Profiler/System Call Trace.... :-(

Comment: unfortunately we cannot help you. Your code is fine. You must solve this thread issue.

Answer (score -1):

Why you use CADisplayLink? I think is not a best way to implement Counting - Label. Try to use Timer for this. Some thing like this:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
      self.textLabel.text = currentCount
}
```

May be best way is change a **label** when you change **currentCount**?

Comment: I already have used a Timer before - same result. I think a CADisplayLink fits better here, since he respects FPS. However, it ends in the same result.

Comment: Sergey, if you want to update the UI with the greatest speed, display link is the right mechanism to do that. If you need updates less frequently, such as in your example, then, fine, use a timer.